# POLICY Mozilla Multiple Products HTML href shell attempt - SNORT

Tags: snort, ids

We've had a few of these alerts get triggered through Snort:

"POLICY Mozilla Multiple Products HTML href shell attempt"

I'm struggling to find any information pertaining to this alert, does anyone have any idea what it could mean?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a recent change to the VRT ruleset from Sourcefire, please see [here](http://www.snort.org/vrt/docs/ruleset_changelogs/2_9_2_1/changes-2012-06-26.html). It's in the policy.rules file (as I'm sure you know) and seems to be generated when an attempt is made to exploit a vulnerability in Firefox (a buffer overflow type attack).

Strangely the CVE [link](https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2004-0648) indicates that the vulnerability is from 2004 with a latest revision in 2008, which I suspect means the rule was always there but this is just part of the ir current re-working of Snort rules and therr categorisation.

This link [here](http://www.snort.org/search/sid/21954?r=1) explains the vulnerability and exploit in much more detail.